# Can these company events affect a stock's price?

Tags: stocks, online-trading

In the events calendar, I see the following events:

- Conference
- Forum
- Business travel
- Summit
- Workshop
- Seminar
- R&D research and development day
- Analyst day/meeting
- Company travel
- Trade show

I see them along with earnings, splits and other events.

Do these have any effect on the stock's price before and after they occur? For example, could a conference result in business partnership/expansion so that price rises directly after it?

Comment: I mean, it'd depend on what happens at them, right? If they demo a new product at a trade show, for example... or if the demo flops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything can cause the stock price to move. The items in your list are general. The question is what happens at those events.

Do they discuss a merger, or the status of a major product line?

Do they attend an industry summit/workshop/conference where it becomes clear they are falling behind, or leading the way?

Does the booth at the trade show demonstrate that they are stagnant or behind others? Is their booth smaller or larger than last year?

Some analysts use these events to gather more data. It isn't the event that causes the change in perception, it is what happens at these events.